# :bnext not cycling through all buffers in vim

Tags: terminal, vim, buffer

For some reason :bnext is not cycling though all the buffers shown by :buffers

I have 5 buffers open but only 3 buffers are visited when I used :bnext repeatedly.

How can I cycle through all the open buffers in vim?

Answer (score 0):

You may be seeing this special behavior documented under `:help :bnext`:

> ```
>   If you are in a help buffer, this takes you to the next help
>   buffer (if there is one).  Similarly, if you are in a normal
>   (non-help) buffer, this takes you to the next normal buffer.
>   This is so that if you have invoked help, it doesn't get in
>   the way when you're browsing code/text buffers.
> ```

To include them in the navigation, use `:setlocal buftype=`

*Unlisted buffers* aren't considered by `:bnext`, neither (cp. `:help 'buflisted'`). But for those to show up in the buffer list, you'd have to use `:buffers!`.